# What is the easiest and fastest way to produce a uniformly distributed random number between 0 and 9 off the cuff?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Let’s assume, you are in a rush and you need a random number: What is the best way to produce a high-quality, uniformly distributed random integer number between 0 and 9, ideally using only mental math or, less ideally, tools that are commonly available (except for computers, calculators, smartphones and books, of course).

Comment: Is this common? http://www.random.org/integers/

Comment: Look at a digital clock and use the ones digit of the minute?

Comment: How fast are you with [scissors and glue](http://www.korthalsaltes.com/pdf/decahedron.pdf)? :-D

Comment: This is more pencil-and-paper rather than mental, but: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toss a fair coin four times.  Put a 1 if the toss is a head and a 0 otherwise.  Make the four tosses into a string of 0s and 1s of length 4.   For example you might get 0110. Convert this binary number to decimal; in the example you got 6. Toss it out and try again if the number is > 9.

Comment: For repeated tries, you can increase the efficiency by throwing 10 coins to produce 3 digits  (try again if the number is in the (1000-1023 range)

Comment: C'est vrai; I was shooting for absolute minimality.